# TFS Email notification with Test Results

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, email-notifications

I have created new TFS build defination with following steps.

**Step 1.** Trigger automation testing.

**Step 2.** Read the execution result and update Test execution result in TFS. (Creates new Run and updates Test plan result)

Note: I have written custom utilities for step 1 and step 2.

I know we can create E-mail alerts on events such "Build completes" from TFS "Control panel > Default Collection > Project > Alerts" but I did not find any way to customize contents of email being sent.

I am looking for TFS way to trigger email **with Recent Test Result** once my build completes.

Answer (score 1):

Since this *Test Case Result* is not a Work Item you can not create a query for build-in e-mail alert.

However, you could use some custom tasks to send mails in the build definition such as [send email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) or [email](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Email) task.

Comment: but how to add recent Test Run Result in this template ??

Comment: @user7494481 After go through more details, suggest you to use some custom tasks which integrates with the build definition to send emails.Please see my update reply. A sample for your reference: http://totalalm.azurewebsites.net/2015/12/11/custom-vsts-task-code-analysis/